# What is my text missing that it won't convert to json correctly?

Tags: python

I have seen answers to similar questions here, but I have spent way too much time figuring out how it applies to my python code! I am a beginner, so apologies in advance that I couldn't figure it out from the other answers.

I am converting a dataframe to json. When I output the text format I want, the output is fine, as follows:

```
def combined_df_json(df):

  today = datetime.datetime.now()
  text = "{"

  for i in range(len(df)):

      text = text + ("\""+ str(df.Tr_Id[i]) +"\":"  \
        "{" \
          "\"id\": " +str(df.Tr_Id[i])+ "," \
          "\"date\": " +str(df.Date[i])+ "," \
          "\"out\": "  +str(df.Out[i])+ "," \
          "\"in\": "  +str(df.In[i])+ "," \
          "\"balance\": \""  +str(df.Balance[i])+ "\"" \
        "}," \
      )

  text = text[:-1] + "}"

  return text

text_combined_csv = combined_df_json(combined_df)

print(text_combined_csv)
```

This returns the following, which is what I want:

```
{"0":{"id": 0,"date": 5/31/2022,"out": 7700,"in": 0,"balance": "892318.0"},"1":{"id": 1,"date": 5/31/2022,"out": 1232,"in": 0,"balance": "nan"}
```

(and so on)

However, when I load it to json, I get an error:

```
with open(path+'cmbd_csv.json', "w") as f:
    f.write(text_combined_csv)

with open(path+'cmbd_csv.json', "r") as f:
        file_contents = json.load(f)
```

```
JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 24 (char 23)
```

EDIT: Here's the complete text if that helps:

```
{"0":{"id": 0,"date": 5/31/2022,"out": 7700,"in": 0,"balance": "892318.0"},"1":{"id": 1,"date": 5/31/2022,"out": 1232,"in": 0,"balance": "nan"},"2":{"id": 2,"date": 5/31/2022,"out": 16056,"in": 0,"balance": "nan"},"3":{"id": 3,"date": 5/31/2022,"out": 80000,"in": 0,"balance": "nan"},"4":{"id": 4,"date": 5/31/2022,"out": 40000,"in": 0,"balance": "nan"},"5":{"id": 5,"date": 5/31/2022,"out": 105805,"in": 0,"balance": "nan"},"6":{"id": 6,"date": 5/31/2022,"out": 185500,"in": 0,"balance": "nan"},"7":{"id": 7,"date": 5/31/2022,"out": 52188,"in": 0,"balance": "nan"},"8":{"id": 8,"date": 5/31/2022,"out": 22544,"in": 140000,"balance": "nan"},"9":{"id": 9,"date": 5/31/2022,"out": 555000,"in": 0,"balance": "nan"},"10":{"id": 10,"date": 5/31/2022,"out": 25000,"in": 0,"balance": "nan"},"11":{"id": 11,"date": 5/31/2022,"out": 10550,"in": 0,"balance": "nan"},"12":{"id": 12,"date": 5/31/2022,"out": 116000,"in": 0,"balance": "nan"},"13":{"id": 13,"date": 5/31/2022,"out": 82300,"in": 0,"balance": "nan"},"14":{"id": 14,"date": 5/31/2022,"out": 0,"in": 0,"balance": "nan"},"15":{"id": 15,"date": 5/31/2022,"out": 349731,"in": 140000,"balance": "nan"},"16":{"id": 16,"date": 5/31/2022,"out": 13280,"in": 0,"balance": "nan"},"17":{"id": 17,"date": 5/31/2022,"out": 140000,"in": 0,"balance": "nan"},"18":{"id": 18,"date": 5/31/2022,"out": 65000,"in": 0,"balance": "nan"},"19":{"id": 19,"date": 5/31/2022,"out": 0,"in": 0,"balance": "nan"}}
```

Would be very grateful if someone could help, I have spent a couple of days on this at this point!

Thank you.

Comment: Python has a `json` module built in. Just create a dictionary and let `json.dumps` do the rest.

Comment: with [jsonformatter](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/#) you can check if your data is valid json in general.

Comment: It seems to be complaining about the dates, which are not quoted.  But as Thomas says, it's much easier to create a dict and call json.dumps on it rather than trying to manually create a valid json structure.

Comment: the date is wrong. There is no datetype in json. Because it has slashes, it cant be a number, so you must quote it.

Comment: Thanks guys. I'll look into the dates and also json.dumps. Regards

Edit: putting dates in quotes fixed it. Thanks! Still will have a look at json.dumps

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @snakecharmerb @The Fool, @Thomas and @ Rabinzel

The issue is with the dates. JSON does not have a datetype, and since it contains slashes, it needs to be quoted as well. This is how that part looks like now and working:

```
 for i in range(len(df)):

      text = text + ("\""+ str(df.Tr_Id[i]) +"\":"  \
        "{" \
          "\"id\": " +str(df.Tr_Id[i])+ "," \
          "\"date\": \"" +str(df.Date[i])+ "\"," \
          "\"out\": " +str(df.Out[i])+ "," \
          "\"in\": " +str(df.In[i])+ "," \
          "\"balance\": \""  +str(df.Balance[i])+ "\"" \
        "}," \
      )
text = text[:-1] + "}"
  return text
```